# iOS segmented controls in Flutter

Tags: ios, user-interface, dart, flutter

[image: scope bar buttons]

I want to create a UI component same as above. Is there any widget for this? If not, how can I achieve this with default widgets? Not all the corners are rounded, so I can't just use a couple of rectangles with rounded corners. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `UIKit`'s `UISegmentedControl`.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/segmented-controls/

Comment: It's called segmented controls not scope bar so my question is duplicate. Thank you for informing.

Comment: @Nobody feel free to delete the question so as to not clutter the site with dupes

Comment: No need to delete. Better to flag as duplicate with a link to the original.

Answer (score 0):

The master already channel contains `SegmentedControl`

```
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/18373
```